# ¿Por que este script, solo funciona las 1ras veces?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, vscode, python-3.8

Estoy escribiendo un script que combine varios pdf en uno solo. He escrito varias versiones del código, las cuales parecen funcionar al comienzo. Después de un rato y ejecutando el Script sobre la misma carpeta y archivos, obtengo este error:

[image: Error al ejecutar el script]

Se que dice que no encuentra el archivo 01.pdf, pero les aseguro que si esta ahi, junto con otro mas llamado 02.pdf.
Algo extraño, es que me habla de errores en las lineas 203 y 114, cuando mi script, tan solo tiene 14 lineas.

El código es este:

````
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

entrada = os.listdir("archivos/")

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for item in entrada:
    if item.endswith("pdf"):
        merger.append(item)

merger.write("archivos/Unido.pdf")
merger.close
input("Archivos combinados, presione una tecla.")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifiqué un poco mi propio codigo, con las sugerencias de vakeroj, y ahora se puede seleccionar cualquier ruta sin error.

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

ArchivoTotal = PdfFileMerger()
ruta = input("Ingrese ruta: ")
entrada = os.listdir(ruta)

for item in entrada:
    if item.endswith("pdf"):
        ArchivoTotal.append(os.path.join(ruta, item))

ArchivoTotal.write(os.path.join(ruta, "ArchivoFinal.pdf"))
ArchivoTotal.close

input("Archivos combinados, presione una tecla.")
```

Comment: Algo que noté, cuando revisé con calma el código, es que la variable "entrada", no se guarda como un "string", sino que se almacena como una lista, por lo que el comando "append", nunca iba funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Yo estoy haciendo lo mismo solo con dos PDF

opino que podrias tener problemas con `entrada = os.listdir("archivos/")` debes procurar que solo hallan documentos pdf y ningun directorio/carpeta

ya encontre el error , esta en `merger.append(item)` , aca solo pasas el nombre del archivo , pero falta su ruta relativa o completa, debes cambiarlo por lo siquiente `merger.append(os.path.join("archivos/", item))`.

Yo lo realizaria de esta forma un poco mas segura

````
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger


merger = PdfFileMerger()
entrada = os.listdir("archivos/")


for item in entrada:
    if item.endswith("pdf"):
        with open(os.path.join(r"archivos/", item), 'rb') as pdf:
            merger.append(pdf)
            pdf.close()
            
        
with open(r"archivos/Unido.pdf", 'wb') as salida:
    merger.write(salida)
    merger.close()

input("Archivos combinados, presione una tecla.")```

Saludos
````

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, pero sigo obteniendo el mismo error, aun con tu código (en la carpeta archivos, solo tengo dos pdf).

Comment: el error esta en  linea `merger.append(item)` , primero imprime variable "entrada" , pues me parece que los errores se deben a las rutas de los archivos a como las manejas , dependiendo desde donde lanzas el script de python , 

en tu carpeta "unirPDF" tienes la carpeta archivos?

Comment: Si, la carpeta ya esta creada. La estructura es así: una carpeta llamada unirPDF, dentro el script + una carpeta llamada archivos y dentro de esta dos pdf (01.pdf y 02.pdf)

Comment: ya encontre el error , esta en `merger.append(item)` , aca solo pasas el nombre del archivo , pero falta su ruta relativa o completa, debes cambiarlo por lo siquiente
`merger.append(os.path.join("archivos/", item))`, testeado

Comment: ademas de esto si lo ejecutas por segunda vez te dara un error , ya que intentara fusionar el mismo archivo "unido.pdf" generado anteriormente, y crear uno nuevo con el mismo nombre y ruta, te recomiendo que simpre que generes  archivo "unido.pdf" lo muevas de lugar o antes de crear otro elimines primero este , saludos

Tambien realice de nuevo el codigo con algunos cambios para mejorar

Comment: Funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias.